# VS Code editing .ipynb file: How to collapse notebook cells?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, editor

I'm editing an .ipynb file in VS Code using the Jupyter Notebook extension. I can't seem to figure out how to collapse (or expand) cells.

Can someone explain to me how to do this (using hotkeys or not using hotkeys), or give ideas for what I might be doing wrong?

I tried each of the hotkeys shown below, under three sets of conditions: 1. with the blue vertical bar on the left-hand side of my cell input selected, 2. with the blue vertical bar on the left-hand side of my cell output selected, 3. with my cursor in my cell input.

[image: "Notebook: Collapse Cell Input" and "Notebook: Collapse Cell Output", with default bindings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the use of this function is not supported in Jupyter of VS Code, you could refer to this link: [Jupyter notebook cell code folding and output view expanding request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1629).

Also, please try to use "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)", right-click in the cell of Jupyter, and select "`Collapse Cell Input`" or "`Collapse Cell Output`":

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Answer (score 54):

And another way to collapse cells is coming to v1.64. See

> #### Cell collapsing UI
>
> Notebook cells have a blue bar on the left side to indicate that they
> are focused. This bar is now interactive - you can click the top part
> to collapse the cell input, and the bottom part to collapse the
> output.

[image: cell collapse demo]

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#cell-collapsing-ui

Answer (score 6):

In my VSCode insiders build version 1.61.0, its working.

What's working ->

```
 a) One shot expand/collapse all cells(code/output) in '.ipynb'(notebook)
 b) Single cell code/output expand/collapse in '.ipynb'(notebook)
 c) code folding in `.py` file with `#%%` (hierarchy style)
```

1. for `.ipynb` (your requirement)

   There is keybinding available: `jupyter.notebookeditor.expandallcells/collapseallcells`

   what it does?

   ```
           Expands/collapses all cells in one shot
   ```

   Find this setting->

   ```
        Top menu File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts
        In search("Type to search in keybindings"...top side) 
        type "Notebook Expand" or "Notebook Collapse", check out:

                Notebook: Expand/Collapse All Cells, 
                Notebook: Expand/Collapse Cell Input and 
                Notebook: Expand/Collapse Cell Output


        Its possible to expand/collapse single/all cells with these shortcuts keys.
   ```

To make this answer complete (others have answered)->

```
    1.  double click gutter area (immediate space on left side of code cell) to Expand/Collapse cell (code/output)

    2.  right click on gutter area to get Expand/Collapse cell (code/output)
```

2. Detailed post for '.ipynb' and '.py' [here](https://medium.com/@vickytrulite/vs-code-for-python-data-science-5a10f6c48cf5)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: In my vscode its ctrl+k ctrl+c.

First, I press on a cell. Then Esc to leave edit mode. Then ctrl+k ctrl+c and it collapses the cell. I think that's the default configuration, but OP mentioned one can find the keyboard shortcut in File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts -> collapse cell input

Answer (score 5):

I'm using version 1.58.2 and this functionality is now available!

Simply right-click a code cell and select 'Collapse Cell Output'.

Alternatively, click a code cell (make sure you are in command mode) and use the keyboard shortcut ⌘K T (on Mac) or Ctrl-K T on Windows.

[image: Collapse Cell Output]

Comment: For rendering reasons, you don't want to collapse Markdown cell inputs, because it squishes the rendered markdown cell ouput also. You need to be able to *only* collapse **Code** Cell Inputs.

Answer (score 5):

The exact thing that worked for me is:

1. Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for 'collapse all cell inputs'
3. Double click of click the plus sign in front of this option and choose a unique shortcut combination (e.g. Ctrl + Shift + C Ctrl + Shift + A)

You are ready to go, now you can finally collapse all your input cells at once.

Answer (score 1):

To take a step further, while clicking on a header or markdown cell, one can use the VSCode shortcut to hide or open multiple cells.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> <- Open with Windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> <- Close with Windows

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> <- Open with Mac

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> <- Close with Mac

Selecting a header will close/open all mark down cells until it finds the next header, and markdown will close/open all cells until it reaches the next markdown cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can customize keys to Collapse/Expand the Input(s)/Output(s) of All/Active cel(s).

Just add the entire code or the part you need to the keybindings.json file:

```
{ // To collapse active cell input
    "key": "ctrl+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookCellInputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To expand active cell input
    "key": "ctrl+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellInputIsCollapsed && notebookCellListFocused"
},
{ //To collapse active cell output
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseCellOutput",
    "when": "notebookCellHasOutputs && notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookCellOutputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To expand active cell output
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandCellOutput",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellOutputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To collapse all cell inputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseAllCellInputs"
},
{ // To expand all cell inputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandAllCellInputs"
},
{ // To collapse all cell outputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseAllCellOutputs"
},
{ // To expand all cell outputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandAllCellOutputs"
}
```

Change key combinations as you wish.