The key combination Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 is not a command
I'm trying to fold all sections in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code. I've read that the combination Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 should achieve what I want. However, when I type it, nothing happens. The message "The key combination Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 is not a command" is displayed.
I checked the Keyboard Shortcuts and the combination Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 is listed there.
I searched in the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), but I couldn't find Fold All anywhere.
I also tried Ctrl+Shift+[, but that only closes the main section and not the sub-sections within it.
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Here is the default for the fold all keyboard shortcut: https://i.sstatic.net/Jp8OOCQ2.png does this match what you have?

@TimothyG. I have exactly that (https://ibb.co/RhBDpGP). The issue doesn't seem to be there.

you want to collapse cell inputs and outputs? or all folding regions in all cell inputs? what do you mean by "section"?

@starball I want to do this (https://jumpshare.com/s/1UGvmng2tWtyu9jzbcrn)

is this covered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/66876197 ?
